# Node progress bar

Tags: node.js

I am currently working on the example presented in the https://github.com/tj/node-progress

I have followed the example word to word, but can't seem to get the functionality of bar.tick() working

```
var req = http.request({
    host: 'download.github.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/visionmedia-node-jscoverage-0d4608a.zip'
});

req.on('response', function (res) {
    //var body = "";
    var len = parseInt(res.headers['content-length'], 10);
    console.log();
    var bar = new ProgressBar(' downloading :bar :percent :etas', {
        complete: '=',
        incomplete: ' ',
        width: 20,
        total: len
    });

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        //body += chunk;
        bar.tick(chunk.length);
    });

    res.on('end', function () {
        console.log('\nFinished Loading\n');
    });

});

req.end();
```

The final output looks like the following

> downloading ==================== 100% 0.0s

But instead should show the progress as the data is received until complete

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you're actually downloading something, that file could have been deleted or anything so your download is just instantly completing because there's nothing to download.